# When using setPage on an AJAX Paginated Tabulator, Pagination Buttons disappear ignoring the paginationButtonCount

Tags: jquery, tabulator

In Tabulator 3.5

When I use the setPage parameter like this

```
$('#myTabulator').tabulator('setPage', 34)
```

The Pagination Buttons that are set on init disappear

like this :

```
{paginationButtonCount: 5}
```

Is there a way to set paginationButotnCount after init, or refresh them so they come back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that the issues you are experiencing are related to the old version of Tabulator that you are using.

If you update to version 4.1 it should work correctly. both the ajax and pagination systems had a complete rebuild in the 4.0 release

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was, and I will be putting in a pull request.

There appears to be a bug with AJAX Pagination. When tabulator calculates the current page this.page it is a string.

For example if I setPage to 3

In the setPageButtons function :

```
Math.min(parseInt(this.page) + o, this.max)
```

Adding parseInt fixes the issue, since it is concatenating this.page ("3") with o which happens to be 2, so if I have more than 32 pages it sets the number of page buttons that it generates to 32.

If you have that many page buttons there is a function that checks the width of the footer against the width of the page buttons span, if the page buttons span is larger, it hides it.